# Will running heroku db:pull affect my production database?

Tags: database, heroku

I'm new to heroku and currently trying to check out a copy of an apps database thats hosted on heroku.

When I run "heroku db:pull --app myapp" I get a warning that looks like:

WARNING: Potentially Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: myapp

I'm confused as to how pulling a copy of the db from the production server can affect the live app? Most importantly, does it do anything to the database which is on production?

Thanks,
gearoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, it won't do anything bad to your production database, the warning simply means it will DESTROY your local database when you pull, likewise when you PUSH it would destroy the remote database.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was thinking - was just very confused about the warning and the fact that the app name specified is that used on Heroku!